# Cannot run Cordova app using "Google Android Emulator" in Visual studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

It shows the following error when running the application using "Google Android Emulator".

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  stapp       1

How to fix the issue for Cordova application? I installed both Java 1.7 and 1.8 on the PC.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) stapp       1   
Error        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)    stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   stapp       1   
Error        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)   stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   stapp       1   
Error        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)   stapp       1   
Error       Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M   stapp       1   
Error       Exception in thread "main"  stapp       1   
Error       java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) stapp       1   
Error        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)    stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   stapp       1   
Error        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)   stapp       1   
Error        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   stapp       1   
Error        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)   stapp       1   
Error       Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M   stapp       1   
Error       Exception in thread "main"  stapp       1   
Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    stapp       1   
Error       * What went wrong:  stapp       1   
Error       Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.   stapp       1   
Error       > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1  stapp       1   
Error       * Try:  stapp       1   
Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  stapp       1   
Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"D:\Users\....\myapp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Users\....\myapp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" stapp       1
```

Comment: Did you configure Tools for Apache Cordova to leverage JDK 1.8? You can find it under Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides.

Comment: Thanks. The emulator can be launched after I manually set up the java 1.8 path. However, running the app using "Google Android Emulator" doesn't launch the app in the emulator? Did I miss anything?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I found the following errors and warning. `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  Warning: No emulator specified, defaulting to TestAvd stapp   
Error  [19336]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\....\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading. stapp   
Error  [10436]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\....\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading. stapp

Comment: Could you please try turn off the Hyper-V by `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` in cmd(run as administrator) and reboot. If it doesn't work. Please try create a new emulator.

Comment: The hyper-V was already disabled - I have two boot options. I booted the one without hyper-V. So I need to delete and create an AVD using "Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager"?

Comment: Yes, please have a try.

Comment: Deleted and created a new Avd. But it still doesn't launch the app when debugging.