# Azure mobile service authentication works in web page not in Cordova app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I've set up Azure and created Angular factory.

```
.factory('client', [function () {
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/");
    return client;
}])
```

In login controller,

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'client', function ($scope, $state, client) {
    $scope.loginFacebook = function () {
        console.log('loginFacebook...')
        client.login("facebook").then(function (data){
            console.log('logged in succesfully..')
            $state.go('menu.events');
        }, function(error){
            console.log('login failed.');
            $scope.err = JSON.stringify(error); // error is {}
            //login failed.
            $state.go('menu.test');
        });
    };
}])
```

The following code works in the desktop web browser (Tested using Ripple). I can log in and it redirects to `menu.events`.

However, it always called the error callback after logging in after build and created a phone app. The value of parameter `error` of the error callback is an empty object `{}`. The following image was flashing very quickly (I recorded the video and captured the screen).

[image]

I tried to change the error callback to redirect the page when the `error` is an empty object as the following. However, I found it will still redirect if I click the back key when prompting to enter username/password.

```
    function (error) {
        if (Object.keys(error).length === 0 /*&& error.constructor === Object*/) { 
            $state.go('menu.events'); 
        };
        $scope.err = JSON.stringify(error);
        console.log('login failed.');
    }
```

---

The following is the full output of `ionic run android -lc`

```
WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
(node:20576) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

There is an error in your gulpfile:
Error: The `libsass` binding was not found in D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
This usually happens because your node version has changed.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to build the binding for your current node version.
    at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:158:11)
    at Object. (D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:16:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:186:21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-users) and tried your code with my Facebook account but unable to reproduce the error. You could take my following key code snippet as reference.

In index.html under www,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'
        data: gap: https://www.facebook.com https://yourappname.azurewebsites.net; style-src 'self'">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app.run()` function:

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    $rootScope.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://xxx.azurewebsites.net');
  });
})
```

My login controller look like this:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.signWithFackBook = function () {
        $rootScope.client.login('facebook').then(function () {

            alert('Login successfully!');
        }, function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert('Failed to login!');
        });
    }
})
```

The plugins I installed:

[image]

At last, it works for me.

[image]

Comment: There are two differences between your solutions and mine. 1) I downloaded and included the javascript file azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js instead of adding it using the plug-in page. I followed some web pages found on the web. 2) You use `client.login('fackbook').` instead of `client.login('facebook').` and it still works?

Comment: Sorry for #2, there is typo issue. It should be `client.login('facebook')`. I updated it.

Comment: I don't see you include any azure related js file in the index.html file? I used to have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src data: gap: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` and I'm trying to convert the way you wrote. Should I keep these `unsafe-*`?

Comment: I used this common in app's root directory `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps` to add the azure related js.

Comment: I used the Visual studio GUI added the `azure-mobile-apps` plugin, it should do the same. I thought it will automatically add the javascript file include in the html file.

Comment: On my side, it add the js file to `myApp\platforms\android\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps` and I do not need to include it in the HTML file.

Comment: I found two files `www\MobileServices.Cordova.Ext.js` and 
`www\MobileServices.Cordova.js` under the folder too. Building now. Hopefully it finally works this time.

Comment: However, you can remove this line: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"...`, and it has no effect on this case. How do you run your app? Are you using Android emulator?

Comment: I had to ask another person to build and run it on the device because my PC doesn't build and my emulator doesn't launch the app when running it using Visual studio. The details can found at the comments of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197862/cannot-run-cordova-app-using-google-android-emulator-in-visual-studio. The experience of VS for Cordova development had quite a few issues.

Comment: You can also run your app on a device, the apk file you can find in `myApp\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk`.

Comment: I tried once and it didn't run on my phone. Maybe I should give it another try.

Comment: You can follow this link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html to set up your SDK environment correctly.

Comment: Updated the app and now it shows a blank screen without the login button. I tried to run it in Ripple and it also shows a blank page in the browser. The Chrome developer tools show the following error in Javascript console: `ReferenceError: WindowsAzure is not defined`?

Comment: I think it is a Ripple issue. Could you run your app with the command: `ionic run android -lc` or `cordova run android`?

Comment: Both Android phone app and Ripple shows the blank screens. What's the paths of  `ionic` and `cordova`? I got `...is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: First of all, please make sure [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) is installed and then you can install them with the following: `npm install -g cordova ionic`.

Comment: I've installed cordova and ionic. However, I got the following error when run the command line at the app root folder. `There is an error in your gulpfile:
Error: The 'libsass' binding was not found in D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
This usually happens because your node version has changed.
Run 'npm rebuild node-sass' to build the binding for your current node version.
    at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:158:11)......`

Comment: Run `npm install` then `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps` and then `ionic run android -lc`.

Comment: However, `cordova run android` launched the emulator. But it popped a message of "Unfortunately, Launcher3 has stopped." After clicking the OK button, it just entered the android main/launcher UI.

Comment: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps` showed "Plugin "cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps" already installed on android.". And `ionic run android -lc` got the same error. I tried `cordova run android` again and this time there was no error message popping up. However, it just entered the Android launder main screen without launching the app?

Comment: If you run `ionic run android -lc`, please take a look at the command line window and you will see that all logs are shown in it.

Comment: I've appended the full output of `ionic run android -lc` at the end of the question.

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in your app directory?

Comment: I just rerun `npm install -g cordova ionic` and got the same error.

Comment: Hi @dc7a9163d9, I mean just running `npm install` in your app's root directory instead of `npm install -g cordova ionic`.

Comment: Just did `npm install` and it output 
`npm WARN ionic-sidemenu@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN ionic-sidemenu@1.1.1 No license field.` However, the `ionic run android -lc` still got the errors.

Comment: Please ignore the warning and run `ionic run android -lc` again.

Comment: Yes, running it again still got the same "gulpfile" error.

Comment: Well, I found [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/npm-rebuild-node-sass-has-no-effect/35401), you may have a try.

Comment: I ran `npm install -g node-sass` and `npm rebuild`. However, `npm rebuild` output the error of `gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\......\myapp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)....

Comment: I have no idea about `gyp ERR! stack Error`. You may try using `ionic start myApp tabs` to recreate your project and migrating your existing code to this project.

Comment: I'm recreating a the App using ionic 2. Is there any documentation on using Azure mobile app on Ionic 2? Especially on adding login to a scaffolded app with template of "Tab".

Comment: Can you attach  or send me the source code you did? Thanks.

Comment: I pushed my project into github. You can check out the repo: https://github.com/achengit/ionic1-auth-quickstart. And I also updated my reply.

Comment: Thanks very much. Will check out.

Comment: I downloaded the code and changed the initial url. And ran `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps`. But I still got the error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: WindowsAzure is not defined`?

Comment: Have you run the app in android emulator?

Comment: It works in android emulator. So the plugin doesn't work for browser (`ionic serve`)?

Comment: In browser you need to include `<script src="https://zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js"></script>` in your www/index.html.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct if you feel so?

Comment: Will the android/ios phone app be affected if I include the `<script src="https://zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-app‌​s-client.min.js"></s‌​cript>` for web browser?

Comment: No, it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use

```
client.login("facebook").done(function (data){
```

instead of `.then`?